# Changing format of many files in Excel

Tags: perl, excel, matlab

I have a folder filled with thousands of csv files. When I open one file, the data looks like:

```
20110503    01:46.0  1527.8  1  E
20110503    01:46.0  1537.8  1  E
20110504    37:40.0  1536.6  1  E
20110504    37:40.0  1533.6  1  E
20110504    36:17.0  1531.1  1  E
```

The second column(time) has minutes and seconds before the decimal point. If I select the second column, right click and click format cells, select time, and change to `13:30:55` mode, the same data looks like:

```
20110503    19:01:46 1527.8 1   E
20110503    19:01:46 1537.8 1   E
20110504    0:37:40  1536.6 1   E
20110504    0:37:40  1533.6 1   E
20110504    8:36:17  1531.1 1   E
```

Now I can see hours, minutes and seconds. I have written a matlab function that reads these files, but needs to be able to read the hours. The function can only be used after I change the format to display the hours. Now I have to apply the function to all the files in the folder.

I'm wondering, is there a way to change the default time display so hours are included? If not, is there a way of writing a script to change the format of these files? Thanks!

Note: the part of my matlab function that reads the file looks like:

```
fid = fopen('E:\Tick Data\Data Output\NGU13.csv','rt'); 
c = fscanf(fid, '%d,%d:%d:%d,%f,%d,%*c');

datamat = reshape(c,6,length(c)/6)'; % reshape into matrix

yyyymmdd = datamat(:,1);    
hr = datamat(:,2);             
mn = datamat(:,3);            
sec = datamat(:,4);
pp = datamat(:,5); % price
vv = datamat(:,6); % volume
```

In Excel:

[image]

In Notepad, you can see hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds:

```
20111206,09:50:56.411,4.320,1,E
20111206,10:02:10.167,4.300,1,E
20111206,11:24:09.052,4.313,1,E
20111206,11:46:09.359,4.307,1,E
20111206,11:50:22.785,4.320,1,E
```

Comment: Where does the hour value come from?  If just plain old `csv` file, changing cell formatting cant add hour data that wasn't in the original text.

Comment: The hour value is certainly in the original file, but it not displayed in the default format. When I click on a time cell, I see the full time including hours in the formula bar.

Comment: If the input file is a `csv` and it contains the hour value, why would excel formatting effect whether or not you can read anything?  `csv` itself has no formatting so it _cannot_ be the problem here.

Comment: Will you post a sample of the original CSV as it looks when opened in Notepad?

Comment: @Lucas, I agree I'm surprised that formatting effects if I can read anything or not, but it definitely seems to. If I run the program without reformatting and saving so that hours are visible, it won't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a record of the type

```
20010402, 09:30:24.456, 4.235, 1, E
```

you should use this fmt:

```
fmt  = '%f%f:%f:%f.%f%f%*s';
data = textscan(fid, fmt, 'Delimiter',',','CollectOutput',true);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm asking the wrong question; if I'm looking at the folder and all the files are Excel CSV files, is there a quick way to convert them all to notepad files?

Comment: Okay I figured it out, Thanks so much everyone. Switched default program to notepad.

Comment: Excel is the program that by default opens .csv files. There is no such a thing like an Excel-csv file. On windows, right-click on a .csv > properties > change, choose other program. Also, it's not the icon that makes a file type but its extension.

Comment: Why are you using `%f` for everything? Isn't that for floating-point number?

Comment: Why not and yes. I like to keep things simple and not looking for performance.